# What if a white light with all the colours of the same phase is produced As a white (LASER)?

Tags: particle-physics, visible-light, waves

What would that kind of white light be useful if is it possible to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would that kind of white light be useful if is it possible to exist

In [this link](http://www.semiconductor-today.com/features/PDF/semiconductor-today-2015-july-august-Arizona-State.pdf) the uses are outlined:

> While this first proof-of-concept is important, significant
>   obstacles remain to make such white lasers applicable
>   for real-life lighting or display applications, says the
>   researchers. One of crucial next steps is to achieve
>   similar white lasers under the drive of a battery. For
>   the present demonstration, the researchers had to use
>   a laser light to pump electrons to emit light. This
>   experimental effort demonstrates the key first material
>   requirement and is expected to lay the groundwork
>   ultimately for white lasers under electrical operation

And from [here:](http://magnetoplasmonics.sbu.ac.ir/a-monolithic-white-laser/?print=pdf)

> A white-light laser has the potential to replace white LEDs in
>   lighting, displays, sensing and telecom, with higher energy
>   conversion  efficiencies  and  higher  output  powers.

Answer (score 2):

In the paper linked to below such a device is reported. It produces R, G and B laser light simultaneously.

https://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2015.149

As far as I know there is no phase relation between the three colors.

Comment: Why the down-vote?